# use static block after writing main method, giving error

Tags: java

//Can anyone help me on the below code, why it is not compiling...

```
 class A
    {
    public static final void main(String[] s) 
        {
            static
            {
             System.out.println("without argument");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the static block outside the main method?

Comment: what did you expect? static init block should be outside the `main` method

Comment: You can't embed a `static` block in a method. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: The correct term is "static _initialization_ block", and per the documentation its purpose is to _initialize_ a class. Method calls can only happen after the class is initialized, per the documentation. So you put these initialization blocks up in the class body itself, not inside other members, in order that they may initialize the class, as their name implies. Read the Fine Manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this won't work because you're just  typing "Static" without explicitly referencing a method, or whatever it is you're trying to do.

A good rule-of-thumb to note from another thread: ask yourself "does it make sense to call this method, even if no Obj has been constructed yet?" If so, it should definitely be static.